# When is a surjective local homeomorphims a covering map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I know that there are examples of local surjective homeomorphims that aren't a covering map, but which propperty has to have the local sujerctive homeomorphims for became a covering map?

Comment: For starters, a covering map is an open map.